# What label references are available in the Information management policy settings for s Word document library?

Tags: information-policy

This is for SharePoint 2010. I know how to use the "Information management policy settings" for a document library to "Enable labels." And I know how I can then, for instance, specify {Version} as a label so that I can use the SharePoint version column as metadata in a Word document, say putting the version number in a Word Document's footer.

What I'm trying to find out is I can use the SharePoint columns "Modified" and "Modfied By" in the same way.

I've tried {Modified}, {ModifiedBy}, {Last_x0020_Modified}, and {MyEditor}, but I get an error saying: There were errors on the page: The label reference, Modified, can not be used in a label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The help text explicitly says

> "You can use any combination of fixed text or document properties,
>   except calculated or built-in properties such as GUID or CreatedBy"

Modified By is a built in field and cannot be used.